# Obtain common elements from subsets of a list in R

Tags: r

My data structure is as follows:

```
listA
[[1]]
1 2 4 5 6 8 9 10 12 24
[[2]]
4 8 9 12 26 35 46

listB
[[1]]
5 8 10 12 24 35 42 56 
[[2]]
26 35 46 59 68 72
```

I want the number of common elements from respective subsets of both list to be stored in a separate list

I am expecting the following result"

```
list_AB
[[1]]
5         #No. of common elements between listA [[1]] and listB[[1]]
[[2]]     #No. of Common elements between listA [[2]] and listB[[2]]
3
```

I wrote the following code to obtain the answer but it was no good:

```
k<-c(1:2)
for (i in k){
for (j in 1:length(listA)){
for (k in 1:length(listB)){
intersect_G[[i]]<-intersect(listA[[j]],listB[[k]])}}}
```

Comment: 3 is the number of elements common to listA[[2]] and listB[[2]]. It wasn't clearly mentioned in the question before and I have edited it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description of finding common elements between corresponding elements of 'listA' and 'listB' and get the `length` of each

```
lst <- Map(intersect, listA, listB))
lengths(lst)
#[1] 5 3
```

---

Or using `pmap` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
pmap(list(listA, listB), ~ intersect(..1, ..2) %>%
                                        length)
```

---

Or using `for` loop

```
out <- vector('list', length(listA))
for(i in seq_along(listA)) out[[i]] <- length(intersect(listA[[i]], listB[[i]]))
```

---

Or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(listA, listB, ~ length(intersect(.x, .y)))
#[[1]]
#[1] 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 3
```

#### data

```
listA <- list(c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 24), c(4, 8, 9, 12, 26, 35, 
46))

listB <- list(c(5, 8, 10, 12, 24, 35, 42, 56), c(26, 35, 46, 59, 68, 72
))
```

#### data

Comment: OPs post is a bit unclear, but based on the expected output, OP seems to be after the *number* of common elements (rather than the elements themselves); in which case you might want to pre-emptively add `Map(function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y)), lstA, lstB)`

Comment: Hmm, it does in my case. Take a look at my post. If you add to yours I'll delete; no need to include both.

Comment: Don't worry; I'll delete; justed wanted to cross-check with you;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Create data
A <- list(seq(1:10), seq(10,20,2))
B <- list(seq(1:5), seq(100,110,2))

#Unlist both lists and check to see which elements are shared. 
new_list <- list(intersect(unlist(A), unlist(B)))
new_list
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```